# How To add a reverse animation when dismissing the overlay in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

```
  showOverlay(BuildContext context) async {





   final animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: Scaffold.of(context),
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 650),
    );

    final animation = Tween(begin: Offset(0.0, 1.0), end: Offset(0.0, 0.0))
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController, curve: Curves.decelerate));



    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 52,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 39,
            right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 39,
            child: Dismissible(
              resizeDuration: null,
              direction: DismissDirection.down,
              key: GlobalKey(),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                print('j');
              },
              child: SlideTransition(
                position: animation,
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 350,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            )
            //  CircleAvatar(
            //   radius: 10.0,
            //   backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            //   child: Text("1"),
            // ),
            ));

// OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
//         builder: (context) => Positioned(
//               top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.0,
//               width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.0,
//               child: CircleAvatar(
//                 radius: 50.0,
//                 backgroundColor: Colors.red,
//                 child: Text("1"),
//               ),
//             ));

  animationController.forward();
    overlayState.insert(overlayEntry);

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));

    

    overlayEntry.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Overlay Example"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showOverlay(context);
          },
          child: Text(
            "Show My Icon",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          //  color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**i wantTo add a reverse animation when dismissing the overlay. I want an ease-out or any other animation when it dismisses. its coming with an animation, Can anyone fix it? Thanks in advance..[image]**

*If you dont mind suggest or edit with a smooth animation*
**i wantTo add a reverse animation when dismissing the overlay. I want an ease-out or any other animation when it dismisses. its coming with an animation, Can anyone fix it? Thanks in advance..[image]**